# Delete all occurrences of a given key in a circular linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to delete all occurrences of a given key in a circular linked list for example:

1 -> 0 -> 1 -> 0

key number = 1  delete all number 1 occurrences and end up with:

0 -> 0

But what I am getting with my code is:

0 -> 1 -> 0 -> 1

It moves head to the end of the list instead of deleting it.

Another problem I found is that if there are 2 or more numbers with the same value next to each other it will always leave one for example:

0 -> 1 -> 1 -> 0

And I get this result

0 -> 1 -> 0

**CODE**

```
    public void remove(int num) {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty List");
        } else {
            Node currentLink = head;
            Node previousLink = head;
            boolean run = true;

            while (run) {
                if (currentLink.data == num) {
                    currentLink.size--;
                    if (currentLink == head) { //Delete head
                        head = head.next; // Deletes head but then it appears on the end of the list
                    } else
                        previousLink.next = currentLink.next; // Deletes all occurrences of a given key but always leaves one if they are next to each other
                }
                previousLink = currentLink;
                currentLink = currentLink.next;
                if (currentLink == head) run = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not handling situation when you are removing a node from the list. For example when you are removing `currentLink` that is not a `head` you are not assigning `currentLink` to the next node (before moving on to the next node). 
You also are not handling a case where you have only one head.
It is much easier to handle each case separately with specific logic on how to move on to the next node. Here is working code:

```
        while (run) {
            if (currentLink.data == num) {
                currentLink.size--;
                if (currentLink == head) {
                    if (head == head.next) { //make sure to handle a case where we are removing head from the list that has only one node
                        head = null;
                        break;
                    } else { //we removed a head, move current head to the new one and set currentLink to the next node from head
                        head = head.next;
                        currentLink = head.next;
                        previousLink = head;
                    }
                } else {
                    previousLink.next = currentLink.next;
                    currentLink = currentLink.next;
                }
            } else { //no match move on to the next node
                previousLink = currentLink;
                currentLink = currentLink.next;
                if (currentLink == head) run = false;
            }
        }
```